# Checking if localstorage item exist directly on div in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, local-storage

how can I check if the localstorage item is not null or it exist directly in div using Angularjs?

I tried to use the code below but it's not working.

```
<div ng-show="localStorage.getItem('itemChecker') !== NULL">
     //show something here...
</div>
```

Comment: did u tried using null instead of NULL ??

Comment: I haven't. Let me try that.

Comment: it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Write an own property:

`$scope.checkStorage = function ()
{
   return localStorage.getItem('itemChecker') !== null;
}`

`<div ng-show="checkStorage()">
     //show something here...
</div>`

Comment: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/37uLez2o/2/) here's a fiddle - its working with this solution